# Is there a trick to the puppetlabs-mysql module on Ubuntu currently?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, puppet, vagrant

There was a running github thread (that appears to be closed and has had a bunch of commits/merges done).

Despite VirtualBox and Vagrant being less then 2 weeks old: *edit: I'm still seeing errors related to /root/.my.cnf.

I updated the mysql and stdlib modules to master.

```
# MySQL Server
class { 'mysql::server':
    config_hash => {
       'root_password' => 'foobah'
    }
 }

#class { 'mysql::server': } have tried it like this to try not having a root password. But it still attempted to use the /root/.my.cnf file. 

mysql::db { 'data_base':
    user     => 'user',
    password => 'pass',
    host     => 'localhost',
    grant    => ['all'],
    charset => 'utf8',
}
```

Whenever it does the commands to create DBs etc as root I get:

```
err: /Stage[main]//Mysql::Db[data_base]/Database[data_base]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf -NBe create database `data_base` character set utf8' returned 1: Could not open required defaults file: /root/.my.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it was an ordering issue (of which I knew better what to look for after developing my own (working) Ubuntu mysql manifest).

The mysql::db part required:

```
require => File['/root/.my.cnf'],
```

Revised with additions:

```
# MySQL Server
class { 'mysql::server':
    config_hash => {
       'root_password' => 'foobah'
    }
}

mysql::db { 'data_base':
    user     => 'user',
    password => 'pass',
    host     => 'localhost',
    grant    => ['all'],
    charset => 'utf8',
    require => File['/root/.my.cnf'],
}
```

Comment: Though I suspect this is a bit of a workaround of something in the module not requiring it. 

Type `Database` does require the class, but perhaps it should also (or instead) require this (through a new property belonging to this file (after `etc_root_passwd` is worked out)). 

Perhaps I should do my first pull request on github.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious, based on the error mentioning the /root/.my.cnf -- what are the permissions of this file? Can you paste the output from this command?

```
stat /root/.my.cnf && lsattr /root/.my.cnf
```

This sounds like permissions might be the issue, but I'd need to see the permissions before knowing as this is not reproducible right now. Also, not important right now, but might be as we delve further; which version of Puppet are you running?

Comment: root@precise64:/home/vagrant# stat /root/.my.cnf && lsattr /root/.my.cnf
      File: `/root/.my.cnf'
      Size: 53         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
    Device: fc00h/64512d Inode: 131079      Links: 1
    Access: (0400/-r--------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
    Access: 2013-01-04 21:28:10.842657561 +0000
    Modify: 2013-01-04 21:28:08.146691454 +0000
    Change: 2013-01-04 21:28:08.146691454 +0000
     Birth: -
    -------------e- /root/.my.cnf

Comment: Puppet v2.7.19

------

Looking at the log I suspect this is an ordering issue. Set password and creating that file is happening after the DB. I've just tried require=>Class['mysql::server'], but it didn't help. Will try with Execs.